# Developer.ean not responding reservation details by passing Itinerary ID and Last Name

Tags: php, xml, api, zend-framework

I am doing PHP Development with developer.ean.com. I want to get API about customer reservation details which I am getting with the help of these url's in developer.ean.com

Description and Diagrams:
http://developer.ean.com/docs/read/hotels/version_3/request_itinerary#ItineraryQuery

Example:
http://developer.ean.com/docs/read/hotels/version_3/request_itinerary/examples/XML_Itinerary_Record

The DFD clearly showing that you can use Email ID or Last Name with Itinerary ID and Confirmation ID.

So I used the following code:

```
public function apiurlAction() {
        //API URL                
        $url = "http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/itin";

        $append = "?cid=55505";
        $append .= "&apiKey=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf";
        $append .= "&minorRev=13&locale=en_US&en_EN¤cyCode=USD";
        return $url . $append;
    }

public function reservationdetailsAction() {
        //getting ItineraryID and emailID
        $itineraryID = $this->_getParam('itineraryID');
        //$emailID = $this->_getParam('emailID');
        $lastName = $this->_getParam('lastName');

        //passing Itinerary ID and EmailID to XML
        $xml = "<HotelItineraryRequest>"; //Open XML        
        $xml.="<itineraryId>$itineraryID</itineraryId>";
        $xml.="<email>$emailID</email>";
        $xml.="<lastName>$lastName</lastName>";
        $xml.="</HotelItineraryRequest >";
        //Created the complete url and use curl for executing it
        $sendurl = $this->apiurlAction() . "&xml=" . urlencode($xml);

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $sendurl);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        $array = json_decode($result, true);

//        echo "<pre>";
//        print_r($array);
//        exit;

        $this->view->customerReservationDetails = $array;
    }
```

Here I got the API reservation details by passing Itinerary ID and Email ID. But not getting by passing Itinerary ID with Last Name.

Same problem with Confirmation ID. I am not getting any data by passing Confirmation ID either with emailid and last name.

Is there any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem with developer.ean.com API.

You can check it with their sandbox :

See this link :

http://devhub.ean.com/V3sandbox/itineraryForm.asp

Answer (score 0):

In the same developement, i am getting Price mismatch issues on my booking pages while prices are fine at successs page and confirmation email. 
Pricing and taxes are returned more on booking page.
response are returned as it is, as we can' calculate our own totals on this, can/t track this issue.